# What was the box in The Bullet Catcher's Daughter?

Tags: rod-duncan, bullet-catchers-daughter

We've just read [The Bullet Catcher's Daughter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bullet-Catchers-Daughter-Gaslit-Empire-Duology/dp/0857665308) in one of the SciFi book groups I go to. I had to speed read it (because I left it late - typical of me :-) and I'm left uncertain what all the fuss was about.

Caution - spoilers follow:

> Orville's box appears to me to be some form of variable power [chemical laser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_laser). The book describes how the wound in Fabulo's hand was cauterised by it (though admittedly it isn't normally spoken of as producing great heat). It also blinds Timpson, which again is typical of lasers at medium powers.

Given this, I don't understand how people thought that:

> the box had the power of transmutation. Specifically of turning lead into gold.

Have I missed something in the plot that explains this, or is this just somewhat casual plotting by the author? I've been back through the (e)book using keyword searching to find anywhere the box is mentioned, but I just don't see the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theme here, and indeed of much of the book, is what happens when people believe things - whether they are true or merely illusion.

> Each person has projected something different onto this artefact. For one it may be capable of extending life. For another it may create gold. And for the Patent Office it may in some way damage the 'wellbeing of the common man'. Elizabeth sees things more clearly, ultimately recognising the container it is in as the answer to her problems.

Comment: Thanks, and I shall think on your suggestion. However it's far from clear to me that the book is that deep. If that was the intention I shall apologise to Rod Duncan (though I doubt he cares what I think :-) but I do not believe it was.

Comment: I can assure you, he does care what you think :)

Comment: I have just blanched with horror at the possibility that A guest might actually be Rod Duncan. If so, pleeeeeeeeeeease put me out of my misery! If you are Rod Duncan I hereby swear to go back and reread the book properly!

Comment: Once the book is out there, the author has no greater right to interpret it than anyone else. So don't blanch! :) As to your question - you could always look for clues in Rod Duncan's Twitter feed @RodDuncan

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaargh! :-)

Comment: Look out for the sequel, Unseemly Science, which comes out in May :)

Answer (score 3):

The "machine" gives every appearance of being a rudimentary chemical laser;

> “A machine? Does it belong to the Duchess’s brother? Is it a gun? A weapon of some kind? Speak quickly.”
>   “It’s a box like this...” He gestured, holding his hands apart in front of him to the width of perhaps a foot and a half.
>   “But what does it do?”
>   **“It draws light in the air.** Easy as drawing a line in the dust with a stick.”

Since the machine is an anachronism, they mistake the laser's ability to *cut* metal for the ability to *transmute* base metals, a logical fallacy based on the assumption that [gold is made out of light](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MV7FRiPl2aQC&pg=PT163&lpg=PT163&dq=way%20of%20the%20crucible%20congealed&source=bl&ots=lDVHt_9O6K&sig=jhXIGCZG8CBzDynRftGgEGnwZbA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-j4oVeeZLcPbariGgJgL&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=way%20of%20the%20crucible%20congealed&f=false) (typically sunlight)

> “The duration of the beam was so brief, it deceived the eye into
>   believing that nothing had happened. And its power... Until then I’d
>   not believed that light could change the nature of metal. But in the
>   place where the beam had touched the iron gatepost, we found a hole;
>   pencil thin and perfectly smooth.”

and ultimately, the machine proves useless in actually creating gold (obviously).

> “He saw that our first goal must be to identify and replicate the
>   reagents. Unless we could make fresh supplies, the machine would soon
>   be useless. Then he said we could combine the light beam with various
>   substances mentioned in the notes of past alchemists – of which he’d
>   assembled a great collection. **He kept reaching into the air as he
>   spoke, grasping it and pulling it back to him, as if he were trying to
>   catch the essence of life.** Together we would defeat poverty, he said.
>   Such was the force of his personality, I couldn’t help but believe
>   him. He shared my goals, I thought. We would do all this together.”

Comment: Thanks Richard, but I still don't see it. This is a post Enlightenment society (it apparently diverged from us at about the time of the Luddite movement) with steam power and airships. A few nut cases may still credit transmutation, but why would an organisation like the Patent Office take it seriously. It just feels to me like an arbitrary and unjustified plot device.

Comment: @JohnRennie - note the 'lead into gold' sequence earlier in the novel. This is a society that fervently wants to believe in alchemy.

Comment: @JohnRennie:
Also, the Patent Office might not even believe the transmutation part, but simply feel it is a Dangerous Devise.