Science fiction novel where technology is strictly controlled (by the church?) and the female protagonist is seeking a device that is a powerful laser
This one came to mind when I browsing through some questions, but only a handful of details came to mind. The protagonist is female (Caucasian, I think?) in either an alternate Europe or a world like it. I think she lives on a houseboat. She acts as an investigator, dressing up as a man when doing so to get people to take her seriously. She's hired to look into a mysterious box with forbidden technology in it, part of the backstory of the setting being that much of the world is run via clockwork (including I remember she had a number of mechanisms in her houseboat that were essentially alarms/booby traps) due to technology being strictly controlled (I don't remember if it was by the government or the church, but I remember an implication that they used some of the technology which they forbade, that it was merely too dangerous for the common citizen) including electricity in almost any variety.
A good bit of the middle of the book is hazy to me, but I remember that part of her investigation ran afoul of that she had to travel into a neighboring country which was at odds with her home country. I don't remember the exact details, but I think they were either considered to be much more conservative/militaristic, or were users of some of the forbidden technology. She might have had some sort of familial connection with the country? Near the end, the encounters the mysterious box, which turns out to be a powerful laser that is unleashed, causing a fair amount of destruction (I think the laser was noted to be red?). I don't remember if she succeeds in delivering it to whoever contracted her, but the book ended with her learning that part of the reward for a successful job is another job (with an implied threat that no one would believe that she wasn't using that forbidden technology and/or that her true sex would be revealed if she didn't cooperate), leading to a second book, which I don't think I ever got around to reading.
I think that I read it as a paperback book from the library in Pittsburgh, somewhere in 2007-2012 time range, and it might have been only a few years old at the time. It was in English, and was probably in the 300 page range based on my memory of its thickness.

This sounds like something from Rod Duncan's series that started with The Bullet Catcher's Daughter.  The protagonist is a professional male impersonator who constantly fears being exposed as a woman, and the plot is all about the all powerful Patent Office that sets out to control forbidden technology.  She does live on a houseboat as well.
But I don't recall any laser and it was written too late for a 2007 to 2012 time range, so it is not a perfect match.

Ah, with that cue, I found https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86002/what-was-the-box-in-the-bullet-catchers-daughter where they discuss it being a laser. I had thought that I was reading it when I was living in Greenfield (I have a distinct memory of the library in question), but it must have actually been later, when I was only working in the area.

As ever I find it fascinating what one remembers.  I didn't (still don't) recall the laser but after reading the other question it seems to have been the McGuffin of the entire novel.  But I certainly do recall that the heroine was a quick change artist who repeatedly escaped capture because her foes did not realise she could change her appearance, including sex, in only a few moments.  I think she masqueraded as a fictional twin brother at times.

Indeed, as a detective, she plays her own twin brother. I had initially sworn that it was titled "The Mad Scientist's Daughter" or some variation thereof, but I'd had no luck with that title. This title makes more sense, focusing on her family's circus background rather than the mad scientist aspect.
